# An awesome but unusual concert

Tags: riddle, knowledge, story, music

> Some times ago, I went to a concert, somewhere south of where I lived.
>   Security had canines, but those were very unruly and attacked each other.
>   When setting up my tent, I wanted to use a stone to plant the stakes but there was none, so I literally prayed for one!
>   Anyway, the concert was awesome - I'm not really a good guy, but I sure like to dance.
>   Still, my mother always told me I caused her many issues, and she was right.
>   Indeed, that day I took some drugs, and I really shouldn't have.
>   Compared to that, I'd rather have been in Hell.
>   But in the end, I enjoyed the concert, even though something was quite strange : most girls went by the same name, one akin to some flower.

**What band did I see?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you went to see

> **[AC/DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC/DC)**

Some times ago, I went to a concert, somewhere south of where I lived.

> This required you to ["Go Down"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9DWwoey1K0)

Security had canines, but those were very unruly and attacked each other:

> This literally was a ["Dog Eat Dog"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8kjqWCCXvU) situation

When setting up my tent, I wanted to use a stone to plant the stakes but there was none, so I literally prayed for one!

> Your prayer was: ["Let There Be Rock"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3f2g4RMfhS0)

I'm not really a good guy, but I sure like to dance.

> You were doing the ["Bad Boy Boogie"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lykP9Opw1Ok)

My mother always told me I caused her many issues, and she was right.

> So you really are a ["Problem Child"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOpafs_mwpo)

Indeed, that day I took some drugs, and I really shouldn't have.

> Be careful not to ["Overdose"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDY6fzBvWtE)

Compared to that, I'd rather have been in Hell.

> So ["Hell Ain't a Bad Place to Be"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNfpkK5Uzqg)

Most girls went by the same name, one akin to some flower:

> which is Rosie, from ["A Whole Lotta Rosie"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAOwDZoWXRI)

Notice that, in order, these are all songs from the album

> Let There Be Rock

Comment: Good job, but there's one missing and the dog-related one can be determined with a simple observation ;)

Comment: Not these ones^^

Comment: Hint : can you guess my favorite album ?

Comment: Still have to correct the dogs song, but you got it otherwise ;)

Comment: @Keelhaul ok, this took some iterations :') nice puzzle!